# Search for specific text in list string and return whole line

Tags: c#, list, search, return

I have a list string:

```
List<string> Entries = new List<string>();
Entries.Add("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
Entries.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet");
Entires.Add("Consetetur sadipscing elitr");
```

Can I search for something like `"fox"` in the list and get the whole line (`"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`) returned?

Comment: You can do a `foreach` for each entry and do `contains` `"fox"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Entries.Where(e=>e.Contains("fox")).FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** You can iterate over `Entries` using `foreach` loop.
**Step 2:** invoke `Contains()` method on every loop item to check required string `(fox)` .

```
foreach (var item in Entries)
{
    if (item.Contains("fox"))
        Console.WriteLine(item); //item found
}
```